GitHub Workflow concurrency not working with scheduled workflows
I had the following main.yml:
# snip ..

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "*/15 0-5 * * *"

The workflow is triggered every 15min.
The problem is that, from time to time, the workflow takes more than 15min to run. Because of this, I modified the above workflow to something else, because I only want one concurrent run at a time, even if that means not triggering the workflow exactly every 15min:
# snip ..
concurrency:
  cancel-in-progress: false
  group: nigthly

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "*/15 0-5 * * *"

The job keeps triggering every 15min, even if there is another job running.
How can I make a GitHub workflow trigger every 15min, but skipping a run if the previous one has not finished?

Concurrency doesn't prevent triggering, but prevents the job from actually running. With cancel-in-progress: false, you'll have on job in "waiting" status if the previous run is still going on. If in that state a third one is starting, the pending one is skipped, and the new job becomes the pending one.

Is there documentation on that specific behavior? I'll keep an eye out anyway.

It's described in this section.
